# Setting a pending breakpoint at a specific address in GDB

Tags: debugging, gdb, symbols, reverse-engineering, breakpoints

I have an application without source or symbols.  I'd like to set a breakpoint in a module that gets loaded some time after running.  The module is loaded at the same base address every time (`0x500000`).  I would like to set breakpoints inside of this module before running the application because I'd like to avoid the work of finding which instruction in the binary loads the module and setting a breakpoint there.

I know about pending breakpoints in GDB, where if I say `break code.c:53` or `break function` GDB will try to evaluate it into an address and if it cannot, it will mark it as pending and try to reevaluate whenever a new module is loaded.  My current problem is that it seems like this functionality does not work for absolute addresses.  If I want to `break 0x501000`, GDB will not mark it as pending even though there is no module whose address space spans `0x501000`.

My question is this: **Can I set a breakpoint at a specific address but tell GDB to wait until that module is loaded?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the command is "b *0x1234"